# Sqoop Export using multiple mappers issue

Tags: hadoop, sqoop

Facing issue in sqoop export to UDB database when we use more number of maps.

We receiving -911 abend (no other process is using the DB)

> sqoop export -Dsqoop.export.records.per.statement=50000 -D
> mapreduce.map.memory.mb=20480 -D mapred.task.timeout=0
> --input-fields-terminated-by '~' --num-mappers '10' --connect 'jdbc:db2://server:port/db-name' --username 'id' --password 'password'
> --table 'table-name' --export-dir 'hdfs-folder-name' -- --schema 'schema-name'

HDFS folder contains around 25 files but this varies for table to table.

Have tried 2,4,10  maps all give -911 abend.

When we use single map data is exported correctly.

Any pointers to resolve the issue will be very helpful.